# Oracle SQLPLUS - how to concatenate variable in PROMPT COMMAND?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

For example, in the beggining of script I get the input from user:

```
Prompt "Type the path where the script will be saved: "
spool '&&PATH\tmp_script.sql'
```

ok, at the end I want to leave some message like it:

```
Prompt
prompt End of commands.
prompt
prompt Execute: @&PATHtmp_script.sql to execute the generated script.
prompt
```

But the sqlplus don't undestand I am trying to concatenate &PATH with tmp_script.sql. I've tried the scape `\`, but don't work on prompt command.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that two ampersands?

```
SQL> prompt "Type path"
"Type path"
SQL> spool '&&PATH\test.sql'
Enter value for path: c:\temp
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> prompt End of commands
End of commands
SQL> prompt Execute :: &&PATH\test.sql to execute ...
Execute :: c:\temp\test.sql to execute ...                        --> here's te result
SQL>
```

Comment: If I use \ it works, but the result is for example (linux): /home/oracle/\tmp_script.sql. the \ still there. As Windows use \ instead of /, it seems ok, but in linux it get wrong. I've tested the && and same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have (nor know Linux) so I can't comment it.

Comment: A double ampersand prefix means remember the value and don't reprompt. Try `select &n + &n from dual;` vs `select &&n + &&n from dual;`

Answer (score 1):

Substitution variables can be terminated with a dot.

```
SQL> define PATH = u:\whatever
SQL> prompt File is saved to &PATH.\somefile.log
```

gives

```
File is saved to u:\whatever\somefile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Actually, I was almost there, need to use `\`, but before we need to use `set escape on` command to make \ as escape, You can check [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/0596007469/re62.html)

```
SET ESCAPE on

Prompt "Type the path where the script will be saved: "
spool '&&PATH\tmp_script.sql'

Prompt
prompt End of commands.
prompt
prompt Execute: @&PATH\tmp_script.sql to execute the generated script.
prompt
```